# How to prevent switching between apps?

Tags: desktop

I want to open an app, e.g. chrome and if I'm allowing other people to use my computer, e.g. to fill out a form or watch a video during a presentation, is there a way I can prevent them from switching over to a different app?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is generally referred as [kiosk mode.](http://tuxdiary.com/2014/11/05/linux-distros-for-kiosks/) But to preserve your access to programs, you may want to configure this under a guest login rather as the default for the system. This also entails disabling access to programs which can launch other programs - which can be tricky.

Alternatively, to be a bit more confident about the integrity of your system, set up dual boot using an encrypted partition for your normal system and a kiosk mode distro on the other